# Importing XML Content to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vbscript

I'm a novice in VBScript and XML coding.However, getting my head around and trying to understand the concepts from W3 Schools and other online forums.

I want to read/parse an xml file using VBScript,my XML file is not data but xml source code from an application.

Below is the code snippet that I'm using -

```
Sub LoadXMLFile()

Dim objXML     'for xml document
Dim objNode    'for xml node item
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.Load ("C:\path\test.xml")
objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
Set objNode = objXML.SelectNodes("/report/queries/query/selection/dataItem/text()")
'MsgBox objNode.Text

For i = 0 To (objNode.Length - 1)
NodeVal = objNode(i).NodeValue
MsgBox NodeVal
Next

End Sub
```

When I step through the VB code the objNode.Length value always evaluates to 0. Not sure why its not calculating the Length.

Here is the xml that I'm trying to parse -

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/10.0/" useStyleVersion="10" expressionLocale="en-us">
<modelPath>
/content/package[@name='GO Sales (query)']/model[@name='model']
</modelPath>
<drillBehavior/>
<queries>
<query name="Query1">
<source>
<model/>
</source>
<selection>
<dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
<expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
<XMLAttributes>
<XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
<XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="attribute"/>
</XMLAttributes>
</dataItem>
<dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product type">
<expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product type]</expression>
<XMLAttributes>
<XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
<XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="attribute"/>
</XMLAttributes>
</dataItem>
</selection>
</query>
</queries>
</report>
```

Appreciate your time and response.

Thanks & Regards
Raj

Comment: Maybe your XPATH does not matching something. Whether this is the case or not we can only determine when we see the XML. Please show your XML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AxelRichter. I have pasted the sample xml code above.

Comment: If you modify your XML like the following, the "text()" won't be empty anymore: `<dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">blabla` (just a silly example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the `dataItem` element has no text node as direct child node. So `...dataItem/text()` will return null.

The `dataItem` element contains element nodes `expression` and `XMLAttributes`. The `expression` contains a text node. The `XMLAttributes` contains further child nodes.

We can iterate through all those nodes if found the `dataItem` elements. Or we can simply get all text content from all childnodes. What we can do with XML DOM Objects is described in [XML DOM Objects/Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760218(v=vs.85).aspx)

The second problem is that there is a namespace defined within your XML. This needs the XML parser to know. If not, the parser will assume all elements outside namespaces  and so it will not find all elements which are within namespaces.

So with your XML you could do the following:

```
Sub LoadXMLFile()

Dim objXML         'for xml document
Dim objNodeList    'for xml node lists
Dim objNode        'for xml node
Dim oAttribute     'for xml attribute
Dim oChildNode     'for xml node
Dim oSubChildNode  'for xml node

Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.Load ("C:\Users\Axel Richter\Desktop\test.xml")
objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:dcc=""http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/10.0/"""

Set objNodeList = objXML.SelectNodes("/dcc:report/dcc:queries/dcc:query/dcc:selection/dcc:dataItem")

For Each objNode In objNodeList
 MsgBox objNode.Text 'the text content in this element and its child elements

 'go through all attributes
 For Each oAttribute In objNode.Attributes
  MsgBox oAttribute.Name & ": " & oAttribute.Text
 Next

 'go through all child nodes
 For Each oChildNode In objNode.ChildNodes
  'if the child node has child b´nodes of its own, go through them too
  If oChildNode.HasChildNodes Then
   For Each oSubChildNode In oChildNode.ChildNodes
    MsgBox oSubChildNode.nodeName & ": " & oSubChildNode.XML
   Next
  Else
   MsgBox oChildNode.nodeName & ": " & oChildNode.Text
  End If
 Next

Next

End Sub
```

With

`objXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:dcc=""http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/10.0/"""`

I define a prefix `dcc` for the namespace

`http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/10.0/`.

The `dcc` is my own choice (**d**eveloper **c**ognos  **c**om). This prefix is needed  for the XPATH in [selectNodes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx) to work properly. Since all the elements in your XML are in this namespace because the root element `report` has this `xmlns` attribute, the XPATH needs to select all child elements of `report` from this namespace. Otherwise it will not work.
So the `dcc` prefix is needed for all elements in XPATH-selects which are in this namespace. If more than one namespace were present, then multiple prefixes would be neccessary.  One for each namespace.

This is one of XPATH's accurate working conditions. The `getElement...` methods will be more tolerant with this namespaces. But in fact the namespace is there and so it should also be respected.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, works like a charm.its just been couple of days I started learning xml and vbscript, I'm trying to understand the logic and the keywords that you have used. I'm going through - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878(v=vs.85).aspx  and trying to use those properties. 

Also, what does that :dcc signify and do I have to use that in the SelectNodes property every time I traverse through the node. 

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @Raj: See my supplement.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, your initial code snippet has set the direction and I'm making good progress with the code. I'm in process of automating some mundane stuff that takes significant time.